# Styling links to look the same as buttons I created in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I created a nice navigation pane for my website in Bootstrap 3 using buttons (btn-group) because I liked the way they looked. Problem is that I found out that you can't wrap links around buttons, as it's not valid HTML5. I want to change my buttons to plain links but can't get it to look the same. Can someone help please?

Incorrect HTML but right styling:

```
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a href="index.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default active">Home</button></a>
    <a href="services.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Services</button></a>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-group .btn {
 border-color: #42C0FB;
 border-width: 2px;
 background-color: #42C0FB;
 }
.btn-group .btn:hover, .btn-default.active {
 background-color: white;
 color: #42C0FB; 
 }
.btn-default.active {
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 5px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .400);
 box-shadow: inset 0 5px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .400);
 }
```

Comment: please create a fiddle or something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should apply the button's css to the link itself and remove the buttons.
It should look something like this:

```
 <div class="btn-group">
    <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-default active">Home</a>
    <a href="services.html" class="btn btn-default">Services</a>
  </div>
```

More info at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons

Edit:

Here is a fiddle:
http://www.bootply.com/GKCf6Vqzki

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. Validated OK as well. Looks like I was over-thinking the whole thing.